# No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo ushort[] en ushort c#

Tags: c#, array

tengo el siguiente problema: Tengo una función para crear un arreglo y como parámetro le paso una constante del tamaño que este va a tener. Debo ingresar por teclado los valores al array pero al retornar el mismo, me dice el error del titulo.

Aqui el codigo

```
namespace Media_CS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const ushort tamanio = 5;
            var arreglo = CrearArreglo(tamanio);
        }

        static ushort CrearArreglo(ushort tamanio)
        {
            //Declaro el array como ushort y le resto uno a la constante
            var arreglo = new ushort[tamanio - 1];
            

            Console.WriteLine("Ingresar valores a almacenar: ");
            for (int i = 0, loopTo = arreglo.Length - 1; i <=loopTo; i++)
            {
                arreglo[i] = Convert.ToUInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return arreglo; //linea de error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te dice que no podes convertir un arreglo en una variable que no es arreglo.

para resolver el problema tu metodo tiene que devolver un arreglo.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const ushort tamanio = 5;
        var arreglo = CrearArreglo(tamanio);
    }

    static ushort[] CrearArreglo(ushort tamanio)
    {
        //Declaro el array como ushort y le resto uno a la constante
        var arreglo = new ushort[tamanio - 1];
        

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar valores a almacenar: ");
        for (int i = 0, loopTo = arreglo.Length - 1; i <=loopTo; i++)
        {
            arreglo[i] = Convert.ToUInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        return arreglo; //linea de error
    }
}
```